# C: Parse a file to obtain number of columns while reading by mmap

Tags: c, parsing, mmap, strtok

I have a file such as the following:

```
1-3-5  2       1  
2      3-4-1   2
4-1    2-41-2  3-4
```

I want to return the number of columns of this file. I am reading the file with mmap in C. I have been trying to do with strtok(), but failing, so far. This is just a testfile, my original file is in GB scale.

```
pmap = mmap(0,mystat.st_size,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE,fd,0);
char *start = pmap; 
char *token; 
token = strtok(start, "\t"); 
while (token != NULL){
     printf("%s \n",token);
     token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
     col_len++; 
    }
```

I have been trying something on these lines, but, obviously there is a logical error. I am getting the following output:

```
number of cols = 1
```

Although, the # of cols should be 3.
It'd be great if you guys can help with any idea on how to parse this kind of a file using mmap. 
I am using mmap because of faster execution for a single pass over the file.

Comment: `strtok` on a `mmap`'d file is probably a bad idea, it modifies your file. You could just iterate over the characters yourself.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But, I want to save computation time, because of the sheer scale of the data. strtok just let's you parse the delimiters, which is useful. Hence, seeking for some input here

Comment: Why not just loop on getc() and handle '\t and '\n' as field/line separators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was actually not correct, as you use `MAP_PRIVATE`, you don't risk destroying your file. But still, if you modify the memory area, the touched pages are copied, and you probably don't want this overhead, otherwise you could just copy the file to RAM from the beginning. So I'd still say: don't use `strtok()` here.

A solution with an own loop based on the functions in `<ctype.h>` is quite simple, though. As I wanted to try it myself, see here a working program to demonstrate it (the relevant part is the `countCols()` function):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L               
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int countCols(const char *line, size_t maxlen)
{
    int cols = 0;
    int incol = 0;
    const char *c = line;

    while (maxlen && (!isspace(*c) || isblank(*c)))
    {
        if (isblank(*c))
        {
            incol = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!incol)
            {
                incol = 1;
                ++cols;
            }
        }
        ++c;
        --maxlen;
    }

    return cols;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [file]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct stat st;
    if (stat(argv[1], &st) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not stat `%s': %s\n", argv[1],
                strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int dataFd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (dataFd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open `%s': %s\n", argv[1],
                strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *data = mmap(0, st.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, dataFd, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        close(dataFd);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not mmap `%s': %s\n", argv[1],
                strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int cols = countCols(data, st.st_size);

    printf("found %d columns.\n", cols);

    munmap(data, st.st_size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! That worked perfectly fine. As you mentioned you are right, strtok() also gave me the correct answer. I saw that the file had space delimited and  tab delimited columns.  Hence catching both solved my issue using strtok(). But, it was good to know the argument against using strtok in these scenarios. Your solution is simple and elegant, as it avoids any built-in functions.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to provide a definitive answer without a definitive question; as written, the question does not contain complete code, does not show the precise input, and does not show the debugging output.

But it is possible to provide some suggestions based on the non-applicability of `strtok` to this problem.

(`strtok` modifies its first argument, so it is really not a good idea to use it with an `mmap`ed resource. However, that is not directly relevant to the problem you are having.)

1. You should ensure that the columns in the file are really separated by tabs. It seems to me most likely that the file contains spaces, not tabs, which is why the program reports that the *entire file* contains one column. If this were the only problem, you could call `strtok` with the second argument `" \t"` rather than `"\t"`. But remember that `strtok` combines successive delimiters into a single separator so if the file is tab-separated and there are empty fields, `strtok` will not report the empty fields.
2. Related to the phrase "entire file" above, you do not tell `strtok` to recognized a newline character as terminating a token. So the `strtok` loop will try to analyze the entire file, counting the last field of each line as part of the same token as the first field of the next line. That is surely not what you want.

   However, `strtok` overwrites the column delimiter that it finds, so if you did fix the `strtok` calls to include `\n` as a delimiter character, you would no longer be able to tell where the lines ended. That is probably important to your code, and it is a key reason why `strtok` is not an appropriate tool in this case. The Gnu `strtok` manpage ([`man strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), emphasis added) provides a warning about this very issue (in the BUGS section at the end):

   > Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:
   >
   > - These functions modify their first argument.
   > - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.
   > - **The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.**
3. There is no guarantee that a file ends with a NUL character. In fact, the file is very unlikely to contain a NUL character, and it is undefined behaviour to reference bytes in the mmap'ed region which are not in the file, but in practice most OSs will mmap an integral number of pages, zero-filling the last page. So 4095 times out of 4096, you will not notice this problem, and the 4096th time when the file is precisely an integral number of pages, your program will crash and burn, along with whatever sensitive equipment it is controlling. This is another reason `strtok` should never be used on `mmap`ed files.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment on why we shouldn't use strtok. I was earlier trying to avoid strtok. But, got into a few issues with getc. Can you provide an alternative/faster way of doing this?

Comment: @AritraBose: To do this on an mmap'ed file, I'd just scan character by character over the input, taking care not to assume that it is NUL-terminated, checking each character with, for example, `isspace`. But you need to specify what "this" means in "doing this". What separates the columns? A single tab? A run of whitespace? Some combination of the above? Are empty fields possible? If so, how are they marked? (For example, if a line starts with a space, was there an empty field before it?) Do you want to know how many columns in the first line? In the longest line? In the entire file? Etc...